# SQL Server Float Datatype Behavior

Tags: sql, floating-point, int, quote, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic SQL SP that acts on dynamically created tables.

A particular query that this SP dynamically generates is given as:

```
SELECT * FROM [DYNAMIC_TABLE] WHERE [RATE] BETWEEN '0.0' AND '10.0'
```

Note that the column `[RATE]` is of type `Float`.

However the same query fails for another dynamically created table in which the `[RATE]` columns is of type `Int`. I understand that this is because of the single quotes around the parameters.

What is the reason for this behavior difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forcing an implicit conversion to occur to make the data types match. This is all about [type precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

For a `float` column, we have the data types `float` and `varchar`. `float` wins, and we attempt to convert `'0.0'` and `'10.0'` to `float`s and succeed.

For an `int` column, we have the data types `int` and `varchar`. `int` wins, and we attempt to convert `'0.0'` and `'10.0'` to `int`s and fail.

Without the quotes, for an `int` column, we have the data types `int` and `decimal`. `decimal` wins, and we attempt to convert the `int` column values to `decimal` and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert/cast the value '0.0' and '10.0' to int

for [Rate] is Float

```
SELECT * FROM [DYNAMIC_TABLE] WHERE [RATE] BETWEEN '0.0' AND '10.0'
```

for [Rate] is Int

```
SELECT * FROM [DYNAMIC_TABLE] WHERE [RATE] BETWEEN convert(int, '0.0') AND convert(int, '10.0')'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [DYNAMIC_TABLE] WHERE convert(float, [RATE]) BETWEEN '0.0' AND '10.0'
```

Comment: your's is a fix, but the above one is the answer for it.